# recover sort order/position values using magmi with multiple website/store/storeviews

Tags: categories, magmi

I've been using Magmi with great success, creating and updating our magento products on a daily basis.

Our production retail site generally uses the default/admin values for store.  When I make new categories and populate them I generally use the category_reset=0 column to preserve the handmade sort order or position values for all of the original categories.

I've been working on a wholesale site set up with a seperate filesystem for all 3 levels of the Magento hierarchy.  I did an import with magmi setting the store column to the wholesale site, with 2 additional collumns - sku and category_ids (without category_reset) using a sub-set of data exported from the admin store view (filtered the manufacturer column for only one manufacturer) to try to populate the wholesale site categories (same root catalog with certain categories disabled or not visible) with the same category products.

For some reason, I'm not sure why, (ouch, I realize now there was a typo in the header name for store) it did not update the right store - it defaulted back to admin and lost 
the sort order for many categories, about 3k products imported ok.

I have 2 non-production sandbox sites with duplicate category data.  I've been manually copying the category product listings with the desired position values into a new csv so I will have sku,category_id (singular),position_value

Many products are members of more than one category.  My question is...

In order to regain the position values or sort order, what syntax should I use under category_ids?  The products are already in the category so I would use a category_reset=0 column, right?

for an example record:

```
sku           category_ids
45000         39,262,353
```

my next import might look like:

```
sku           category_ids      category_reset
abc           39::10            0
def           39::20            0
45000         39::30            0
ghi           262::10           0
45000         262::20           0
jkl           262::30           0
45000         353::10           0
mno           353::20           0
```

does this seem workable?  I'm feeling very gunshy after having borked my production site with a typo and need some validation before I take steps to confuse myself further.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [Magmi Documentation for Importing item positions in categories (from magmi version 0.7.18)](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Import_categories#Importing_item_positions_in_categories_.28from_magmi_version_0.7.18.29), the syntax is as follows:

```
sku,....,category_ids
000001,...,"8::1" < = put sku 00001 at position 1 in category with id 8
000002,...,"9::4,7" < = put sku 00002 at position 4 in category with id 9 and at position 0 in category with id 7
000003,...,"8::10" <= put sku 00002 at position 10 in category with id 8
```

So yes, your method should work.  Be sure to do a full database backup before doing major import changes ;)